# What's wrong in this SQL Query? I am trying to update a column value

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I would like to know what is wrong in below stored procedure as I am not returning any error but at same time I am unable to update my Watermarkvalue column. it returns NULL.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateWatermark] 
 @tableName nvarchar(500)

AS 
BEGIN

 DECLARE
 /* ============= Variables ============= */
  @watermarkValue  nvarchar(MAX)

  DECLARE
 /* ============= Variables ============= */
  @tabName  nvarchar(MAX)

  Set @tabName ='SELECT '+ @watermarkValue +'= MAX([LOAD_DATE]) FROM '+ @tableName

 Execute sp_executesql @tabName



 UPDATE dbo.WatermarkTable
 SET  WatermarkValue  = @watermarkValue 
 WHERE TableName = @tableName 
END
```

Here my WatermarkValue always return NULL. The watermark table has columns as TableName and WatermarkValue and LOAD_DATE is a column in another table in database

Comment: You appear to have bigger problems here, such as the huge injection issue with your `@tableName` parameter. What is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never set your variable @Watermarkvalue to anything, so the value of the variable is NULL.

So this line:

```
Set @tabName ='SELECT '+ @watermarkValue +'= MAX([LOAD_DATE]) FROM '+ @tableName
```

Will always be NULL.

You want to fill your variable, so think you need something like this: (change to correct datatype)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateWatermark] 
 @tableName nvarchar(500)

AS 
BEGIN

 DECLARE
 /* ============= Variables ============= */
  @watermarkValue  nvarchar(MAX)

  DECLARE
 /* ============= Variables ============= */
  @tabName  nvarchar(MAX)

  DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
  SET @ParmDefinition = N'@watermarkValue int OUTPUT';

  SELECT @tabName = N'SELECT @watermarkValue = MAX(ID) FROM ' + @tablename;  

 Execute sp_executesql @tabName,@ParmDefinition,@watermarkValue=@watermarkValue OUTPUT;

 UPDATE dbo.WatermarkTable
 SET  WatermarkValue  = @watermarkValue 
 WHERE TableName = @tableName 
END
```

Comment: I would also `FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@tablename)` and maybe even first check that it is a table and that it is in the `dbo` schema. See https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/ and https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/

Comment: I'd recommend changing the datatype of `@tableName` to `sysname` as well; 372 of those characters are wasted.

Comment: on running above changes now I get this error : 
sg 208, Level 16, State 6, Procedure usp_UpdateWatermark, Line 2 [Batch Start Line 5]
Invalid object name 'dbo.usp_UpdateWatermark'.